# Downloaded Grapevine solution fails to build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, grapevine

I have downloaded http://sukona.github.io/Grapevine/

When I try to build the downloaded solution Grapevine.soln in Visual Studio 2013 without editing anything I get 237 compilation errors such as the following:

> Error 32  Unexpected character '\'    C:\Users\a\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Grapevine-master\src\Grapevine\Server\PublicFolder.cs 193 80  Grapevine
>
> Error 28  Unexpected character '$'    C:\Users\a\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\Grapevine-master\src\Grapevine\Server\PublicFolder.cs 91  80  Grapevine

Am I supposed to edit contents of the downloaded code before attempting to build it? If so how?

Comment: If you are only trying to use Grapevine, you can install it into your project using NuGet and avoid compiling it yourself altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Grapevine uses C# 6 language features that are not normally available in Visual Studio 2013. e.g. the errors referring to unexpected '$' characters are because of attempts to use the new string interpolation feature. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160(v=vs.140).aspx